# Take photo from Library and camera in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Any one can help me for taking a photo from photo library and also take photo using camera in cocos2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

[Using UIImagePickerController](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/)

[UIImagePickerController tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html)

[UIImagePickerController sample tutorial](http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController)

Comment: It's not an appropriate solution

Comment: Is there similar solution for Cocos2d-x?